# Pandas vectorization

Tags: python, sql, pandas, asynchronous, vectorization

In my python script I need to perform a series of sql queries on similar(but not related) tables in the same database. The output columns for each select are always the same. Is there a way to perform this asynchronous to reduce processing time?

```
tables =  pd.DataFrame(['Table1, Table2, Table3'], columns=['Table Name'])
sqlQuery1 = '''select a, b, c from TABLENAME'''

sqlDataLst = []
for i, row in tables.iterrows():
    
    sqlQuery1_exe= sqlQuery1.replace("TABLENAME",row['Table Name'])
    sqlData = pd.read_sql_query(sqlQuery1_exe,getConn())
    sqlDataLst.append(sqlData)
        
sqlDataAll = pd.concat(sqlDataLst)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need [such alike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167975/5841306) logic ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multi-threading. Define a new function (let's call it `new_function`) that gets the table name as an argument and then runs `read_sql_query`.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
   for i, row in tables.iterrows():
      future = executor.submit(new_function, row['Table Name'])
```

Note: When you use multi-threading in python, you should be aware of GIL (and Pandas' developers are careful about this)

Comment: Appending to sqlDataLst within the for loop did not improve the speed. However, filling a list within the for loop using `future[i] = execu...` and then looping through this afterwards to get the data did the trick. Thank you :-)

Comment: Good to know. Happy to hear that it helped.