# Error while performing multiple operations on database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have to loop over all rows in the database and have to update them at some location. I have written this code:

```
import sqlite3
con=sqlite3.connect("Models.db")
c=con.cursor()
c1=con.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE ABC(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, COLVAL text)")
///inserted a few rows........
for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM ABC"):
  if $(any condition): 
     with con: 
       c1.execute("UPDATE ABC SET COLUMN1=(:COLVAL) WHERE id=(:id)",{'COLVAL':'XYZ','id':row[0]})
```

but I get an error:

> OperationalError: database is locked

in the second query, c1.execute("UPDATE ABC SET COLUMN1=(:COLVAL) WHERE id=(:id)",{'COLVAL':'XYZ','id':row[0]})

I do not want to fetch all rows at a time and apply for a loop, as there is a lot of data. Just one row at a time which in my case:

```
"for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM ABC")"
```

line is doing.

Does anyone know the solution for it?

Comment: Your code updates only the row with id=2. Why do you need that loop?

Comment: That I included just for people understanding​ that there will be some condition over which I'll be updating query. Ok, I've updated the question

Comment: Maybe the conditions can be written directly inside the UPDATE statement and you don't need to fetch any row. The sample code in your question does not provide enough info about your requirement.

Comment: The error is coming while executing the second query only

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can loop within a list such as `c.execute("SELECT * FROM abc").fetchall()`

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc(id INT PRIMARY KEY, column1 TEXT)")
///inserted a few rows........
for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM abc").fetchall():
    if $(any condition):
        c.execute("UPDATE abc SET column1=(?) WHERE id=(?)",('XYZ',row[0],))
con.commit()    
con.close()
```

Additionally;

- add `IF NOT EXISTS` to the DDL Statement
- replace parameter placeholders with question marks as being securer
- no need to open more than one cursor
- don't miss commiting the DML Statement at the end

**extra tip :** use `executemany` as

```
c.executemany("UPDATE abc SET column1=(?) WHERE id=(?)",[('XYZ',row[0],)])
```

instead of `execute` for the DML statement for the multiple data as being more performant. Indeed, you don't need for this current case as only concerns with only one row for each `id` value

Comment: Hi Barbaros, thanks for your great answer. It's working fine. What I know is that fetchall() fetches the entire table at once, this could cause a RAM issue that is why I want to read one row at a time. Do you have any idea about this? I'm very new to SQL, can you tell me what could be the issue with two cursors?

Comment: Hi @Thunder , thank you, too. You can set `c.itersize` or `c.arraysize` to a proper value. Check out my former [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167975/5841306) for Oracle db related to proper `c.arraysize` setting. Opening more than one cursor might be redundant if not really needed, just like in this case.