# sqlite3 - executemany alternatives to speed up insert from records of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, database, sqlite

Using `pandas` and `sqlite3`.

I have about 1000 `csv` files with data that needs a little bit of prunning and then I have to insert them into a `database`.

The code I am using:

```
def insert_underlying(underlying_df, conn):
    # convert timestamp to timestamp dtype
    underlying_df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(underlying_df['timestamp'])
    # underlying_df = underlying_df.tail(len(underlying_df)-1)
    # sort it
    underlying_df.sort_values('timestamp', inplace=True)
    # remove the contractname column
    underlying_df = underlying_df[['timestamp', 'close', 'bid', 'ask']]
    # insert underlying into tickdata
    # check if table exists # if it doesn't create
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}tick(timestamp timestamp, close REAL, bid REAL, ask REAL)" .format(symbol))
    # Insert to external db
    query = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ' + symbol + 'tick (timestamp, close, bid, ask) VALUES (?,?,?,?)'
    conn.executemany(query, underlying_df.to_records(index=False))
    conn.commit()
```

From what I have read on similar questions, `executemany` is iterating over the rows and inserting the records. This is very slow. My experience with `sql` is beginner at best.

What would be the best/fastest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't execute separate queries for each row. `executemany()` should merge them into a single query with multiple lists after `VALUES`

Comment: But is there a reason you're not using `underlying_df.to_sql()`?

Comment: @Barmar, looking into `underlying_df.to_sql()` now. I wonder would `to_sql()` be much faster? I have to insert the file by file, no way around that.

Comment: `to_sql` seems very promising. I will try it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But I'm not sure if `to_sql()` can do `INSERT OR REPLACE`. I think it only does `INSERT`

Comment: @Barmar good point on the `INSERT OR REPLACE`, got excited quickly there.

Comment: I think your code should already do it the best way.

Comment: You can set `cur.arraysize` like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167975/5841306) while keeping on using `executemany` as in the current case.

Comment: @Barmar AFAICT `sqlite3.executemany` executes a separate statement for each set of values (try it with `conn.set_trace_callback(print)`).  (Psycopg2 does [too](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany)).  This is [permitted by PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany).

Comment: That's too bad. The equivalent function in mysql connector does batch them, and I assumed they would copy that behavior.